# IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 690: Failed to read scanline 690 error when processing a vrt file

Tags: gdal, vrt

I am working with a rather big .vrt file (38 tiles, sum size is 4Gb) and I get an error

```
IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 690: Failed to read scanline 690
```

It is probably due to non-square tiles.
This problem was discussed for example [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/1179) but I can't find the solution.
It should be some GDAL flag or option to deal with such tiles.

I tried to recreate vrt in QGIS. It's strange that some tiles were saved with `\` slashes and some with `/` !

```
<ComplexSource resampling="lanczos">
  <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">Y:\srtm_eurasia\Env\EarthEnv-DEM90_N65E140.bil</SourceFilename>
  <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
  <SourceProperties RasterXSize="6000" RasterYSize="6000" DataType="Int16" BlockXSize="6000" BlockYSize="1" />
  <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="6000" ySize="6000" />
  <DstRect xOff="48000" yOff="6000" xSize="6000" ySize="6000" />
  <NODATA>-32768</NODATA>
</ComplexSource>
<ComplexSource resampling="lanczos">
  <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">Y:/srtm_eurasia/Env/EarthEnv-DEM90_N70E110.bil</SourceFilename>
  <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
  <SourceProperties RasterXSize="6000" RasterYSize="6000" DataType="Int16" BlockXSize="6000" BlockYSize="1" />
  <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="6000" ySize="6000" />
  <DstRect xOff="12000" yOff="0" xSize="6000" ySize="6000" />
  <NODATA>-32768</NODATA>
</ComplexSource>
```

Comment: 17 years old and fixed bug report is not the best source of information. The error that you see means usually that there is something wrong in a source image. Try if you could find the problematic image by removing images from the vrt one by one. Or make a test conversion with gdal_translate for each image. If conversion succeeds for every file then the theory about a damaged image is wrong.

Comment: I managed to convert it in whole in QGIS, so...

Comment: ...so there is a mystery because QGIS is using GDAL

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem with slashes. I changed every slash that was , but I should change only those which are included into path.
After recreation of vrt file I changed the beginning of paths to mounted folder name and then changed all occurences with \ slashes to /, it was strange that QGIS generated some paths with \ and some with / slashes.